# Entity tagging in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

I would like to tag particular entities from Elastic. Is this supported?
e.g. For the text:

`Hello my name is Johnny`

To tag it to the tokens

`Hello
my 
name
is
johnny < person`

And later highlight those entities?
Does anyone know of such thing or plugin or any point of direction would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not do named entity recognition. You could use an ingest processor, though, similar to this one https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp (though you would probably have to modify it for your exact use case).

However, you're probably better off doing named entity recognition before indexing your documents. You could try openNLP or NLTK, or if it's a non-commercial project, the Stanford NER. I think you want to add the "highlight" tags yourself, also before indexing. I'm thinking of something like this:

`<ne type="person">Johnny</ne> is from <ne type="place">New York</ne>`

You can use a custom analyzer to discard the tags for analysis, or simply index two fields, one without the tags.

Comment: Yes I thought of this. Thanks for the analyzer suggestion to discard the tags. My alternative was make up a tags which are unlikely to be searched.

Answer (score 1):

**POS tagging**

If you mean part-of-speech tagging Elasticsearch doesn't support it.

You should do it by yourself, using for example NLTK, then index your documents tagged.

**Highlight**

Concerning highlighting yes elasticsearch support it, here is the documentation:

[Higlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)

Comment: I didn't mean POS tagging but something similar... thanks for the answer